# Show item number only in the minicart header

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I have achieved to **show item number only** in the mini cart header with following changes.(OpenCart 2.2.0.0)

```
catalog/language/<YOUR_LANG>/common/cart.php
```

Find

```
"Shopping Cart %s item(s) - %s"
```

Replace this

```
"Shopping Cart %s"
```

Above modification working is fine in default. but, **It is not work when add or remove item from mini-cart**. Does show default style.

**This is work on page load after above our modification.**

```
Shopping Cart: 1
```

**but, I have click on "Add to Cart" button & then add item in minicart. So, it will display again this default style. also, does not work when click on remove button in minicart for remove item from minicart**

```
Shopping Cart: 1 item(s) - $602.00
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to modify these two files:

```
catalog/language/Your_lang/common/cart.php
catalog/language/Your_lang/checkout/cart.php
```

The first one is used for default text, and the second one is called for events such add or delete.

Comment: I already modify first one. also, Here, I am not talk about Chekout cart page. My issue is, when, I have click on Add To Cart button from Home page. So, It item add in minicart. So, that's time, minicart heading is default style. It will not still display only item.

Comment: modify above files works for me on any page, including home page, did you try?

Comment: Thanks, I needed this. For OpenCart 3.0.3.2 I figured I need both language files `catalog/language/en-gb/common/cart.php` and `catalog/language/en-gb/checkout/cart.php` to get the same results.

Comment: @emgx That's great!